# How to account for paired observations in statistical tests other than t-test (e.g. regression)?

Tags: r, lm, lme4, mixed-models, lmertest

How to account for paired observations in statistical tests other than `t-test`? Below I discuss two examples in which I try to do so with a mixed-effect approach and fail.

**Example 1: how to reproduce `t.test(..., paired=T)` in `lm()`?**

```
# simulate data
set.seed(66)
x1 <- rnorm(n=100, mean=30, sd=6)
x2 <- rnorm(n=100, mean=60, sd=6)

# arrange the data in a dataset
dd <- data.frame(ID=rep(paste("ID", seq(1,100, by=1), sep="_"),2),
                        response=c(x1,x2),
                        group=c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 100))
                        )
t.test(x1,x2, paired=F)
summary(lm(response~group, data=dd)) # same outcome
```

If the observations are paired one can account for it with `t.test()` but how to do so in `lm()` (if at all possible)? I tried to use a mixed-effect model approach, but:

```
summary(lmerTest::lmer(response~group + (1+group|ID), data=dd))
```

Gives an error:

```
Error: number of observations (=200) <= number of random effects (=200) for term (1 + group | ID);
the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

While:

```
summary(lmerTest::lmer(response~group + (1|ID), data=dd))
```

Runs but the fixed effect parameter estimates and associated Std. Errors and t values are identical to those produced by `lm()`.

**Example 2: linear regression with paired observations**

Let's imagine that the observations in the dataset I created were from subjects measured 30 days apart - namely, each of the 100 subjects were measured on day 0, then again on day 30 - and we wanted to estimate the rate of change over time:

```
dd$time=c(rep(0,100), rep(30, 100)) # add "time" variable to dd
```

Data look like this (linear regression in black, paired data linked by red lines):
[image]

```
lm1 <- lm(response~time, data=dd)
```

`lm1` does not account for the paired nature of the observations.
I thought of running a mixed-effect model that allowed for each pair of data to differ in intercept and slope, but R protests again that I am trying to estimate too many parameters:

```
lmerTest::lmer(response ~ time + (time | ID), data=dd)
# Error: number of observations (=200) <= number of random effects (=200) for term (time | ID);
# the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

A simpler model that allows data pairs to differ in intercept but not in slope, namely:

```
lmer(response ~ time + (1 | ID), data=dd)
```

Complains that:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

But runs and produces fixed effect estimates that are identical to those produced by `lm()`.

**[UPDATE]**

@Limey reminded me that a paired t-test is nothing but a t-test assessing whether the pairwise differences between the two groups differ from zero. Such pairwise difference could be used to perform any paired statistical test beside a t test. To verify this I created three different "Response" variables that are a combination of `x1` and `x2` ordered in different ways (respectively: original random order; `x1` in increasing and `x2` in decreasing order; both in increasing order).

```
dd$response2 <- c(sort(x1, decreasing = FALSE), sort(x2, decreasing = T))
dd$response3 <- c(sort(x1, decreasing = FALSE), sort(x2, decreasing = F))
```

[image]

I calculated the corresponding differences:

```
dd$diff1 <- c((dd$response[1:100]-dd$response[1:100]), 
                (dd$response[101:200]-dd$response[1:100]))
dd$diff2 <- c((dd$response2[1:100]-dd$response2[1:100]), 
                (dd$response2[101:200]-dd$response2[1:100]))
dd$diff3 <- c((dd$response3[1:100]-dd$response3[1:100]), 
                (dd$response3[101:200]-dd$response3[1:100]))
```

[image]
And used them to perform linear models:

```
lm2.diff1 <- lm(diff1~time, data=dd)
lm2.diff2 <- lm(diff2 ~time, data=dd)
lm2.diff3 <- lm(diff3 ~time, data=dd)
```

I expected them to differ in their slope estimates, but they were all the same:

```
summary(lm2.diff1)$coeff[2] # 0.9993754
summary(lm2.diff2)$coeff[2] # 0.9993754
summary(lm2.diff3)$coeff[2] # 0.9993754
```

Their slope estimate is the same estimated from the corresponding "unpaired" linear models (`lm(response~time)`, `lm(response2~time)`, and `lm(response3~time)`). What am I missing?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23276/paired-t-test-as-a-special-case-of-linear-mixed-effect-modeling ; https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q2/006091.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! There are a couple of tricky bits here.

0. We can start by calculating the paired test via `t.test()` and by hand:

```r
pairedtest1 <- t.test(x1,x2, paired=TRUE)
d <- x1-x2
n <- length(x1)
tstat <- mean(d)/(sd(d)/sqrt(n))                    ## -37.58846
pval <- 2*pt(abs(tstat), lower.tail=FALSE, df=n-1)  ## 2.065802e-60
all.equal(pairedtest1$p.value,pval) ## TRUE
all.equal(unname(pairedtest1$statistic),tstat) ## TRUE
```

1. As you found out, the model with a random intercept *and* among-group variation in treatment is overfitted when used in a linear mixed model when there is only one observation of each treatment per group; a similar example is given [here](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/uqam/mixedlab1.html). You can force `lmer` to fit it if you want:

```r
m0 <- lme4::lmer(response~group+(group|ID), data=dd, REML=TRUE,
                 control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore", calc.deriv=FALSE))
```

(Note that we can also see if two models are giving equivalent fits by comparing the log-likelihoods or REML criteria - when we have overfitted models like this one, different models can get equivalent fits with different linear combinations of model parameters ...)

If we run

```
library(lmerTest)
coef(summary(as(m1,"lmerModLmerTest"),ddf="Kenward-Roger"))["groupB",]
```

(the default Satterthwaite ddf calculation fails here) we get

```
    Estimate   Std. Error           df      t value     Pr(>|t|) 
2.998126e+01 7.976192e-01 9.900000e+01 3.758844e+01 2.065922e-60
```

the t-statistic and p-value very closely match the results above (I could just have said `summary()` but wanted to pull out this specific row of the coefficient table).

2. Now let's try the reduced model

```r
m1 <- lme4::lmer(response~group+(1|ID), data=dd, REML=TRUE)
```

As you noted, the fit is singular (if you check, the RE variance will be listed as 0).  Here the t-statistic and p-value are a little off (at this moment, I'm not quite sure why the previous model worked!).  The reason is that, for this data set, the within-group variance is slightly *greater* than the between-group variance. In general we expect `var(between) = sigma^2_between + sigma_2_within/n`, and this works asymptotically/in expectation, but in small data sets the ordering can be in the direction we observe here, in which case we would need a *negative* variance in order to perfectly fit the data.

```r
resids <- with(dd,response-ave(response,group, FUN=mean))
wv <- var(resids-ave(resids, dd$ID, FUN=mean))    ## 15.82
bv <- var(tapply(resids, list(dd$ID), FUN=mean))  ## 14.92
```

(If we fit the same model with `lme` it *appears* OK and gives us a small [but non-zero] estimate for the among-group intercept variance, but if we try `intervals(m2)` it complains that the approximate var-cov matrix is not positive definite ...)

3. As Gang Chen pointed out in a [2011 post to r-sig-mixed-models](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q2/006091.html), we can fit the model we want by allowing a *negative* correlation between the two observations within a group (the additive model shown above only allows non-negative correlations):

```r
library(nlme)
m2 <- lme(response~group,random=list(ID=pdCompSymm(form=~group-1)),
          data=dd,method="REML")
all.equal(tstat^2, anova(m2)[["F-value"]][2]) ## TRUE
all.equal(pval, anova(m2)[["p-value"]][2])    ## TRUE
```

The p-value from `anova()` matches our result above, and the F-statistic matches the *square* of our t-statistic.

4. We can also do this in `glmmTMB`: we have to be a little bit careful because the default `cs()` covariance structure in `glmmTMB` allows different variances for each term, while `corCompSymm` imposes a homogeneous variance:

```r
m3 <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(response~group+cs(group-1|ID),
                       data=dd, REML=TRUE)
m4 <- update(m3,  map=list(theta=factor(c(1,1,2))))
```

(the `map` argument sets the first two elements of the random-effects parameter vector, which correspond to the log-sd of the variation in the first group and the second group, to be identical)

The coefficient table gets the t-statistic (which it calls a z value) correct, but doesn't have a concept of "denominator degrees of freedom", so does a Z-test rather than a t-test ...

```r
coef(summary(m4))$cond["groupB",]
            Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)
groupB      29.98126  0.7976217 37.58832        0
```

Comment: Many thanks. I've been using MEM a lot lately, which sent me in the beautiful rabbit hole that is understanding how they actually work instead of only using them as a black box. I should look into the difference between ML and REML again, as well as understanding the nitty-gritty of var-covar matrices instead of just staring at them blankly like I would with Russian names in a Tolstoj novel (i.e. I know more or less what they stand for but if you asked me to explain it to others I wouldn't be able to). By the way, many thanks for your relentless online support to MEM users over the years.

Answer (score 4):

A paired t-test simply tests whether the mean value (of the differences between the two groups) is zero.  So to "simulate" the results of a paired t-test by other means, simply pre-calculate the difference and pass that to your test of choice.  Using your example:

```
x1 <- rnorm(n=100, mean=30, sd=6)
x2 <- rnorm(n=100, mean=60, sd=6)
diff <- x1-x2
dd <- data.frame(response=diff)
# Standard paired t-test
t.test(x1,x2, paired=T)


    Paired t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -36.167, df = 99, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -31.93760 -28.61546
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              -30.27653
```

Now a "simulated" t-test...

```
t.test(diff)

    One Sample t-test

data:  diff
t = -36.167, df = 99, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -31.93760 -28.61546
sample estimates:
mean of x 
-30.27653
```

And now as a  linear model

```
summary(lm(response~1, data=dd)) 


Call:
lm(formula = response ~ 1, data = dd)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-18.473  -7.328   0.614   6.101  20.764 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -30.2765     0.8371  -36.17   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.371 on 99 degrees of freedom
```

Comment: Of course! I'm learning yet again something that I used to know and managed to forget. Here's a funny thing though: if I code `dd$diff <- c((x1-x1),(x2-x1))` and test `lm(diff ~ time, data=dd)` the slope is exactly the same as the one estimated via  `lm(response ~ time, data=dd)`. Given that `diff ~ time` accounts for "pairedness" while `response ~ time` doesn't (or shouldn't), I don't understand how it is possible.

Comment: Question updated to include, in greater detail, the new can of worms mentioned above.

Comment: I was missing the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> Their slope estimate is the same estimated from the corresponding
> "unpaired" linear models (`lm(response~time)`, `lm(response2~time)`,
> and `lm(response3~time)`). What am I missing?

It makes sense that the overall slope is the same in the three models, being the mean of all the pairwise slopes (something that would be easy to confirm).
What  I was missing is that, in the case of `lm2.diff3`, the StdErr around the slope estimate is about one order of magnitude smaller than in `lm2.diff1` and `lm2.diff2`.
`lm2.diff3` is performed on `Response3` that is a lot more uniform in the behaviour of each pair of observations compared to `Response1` and `Response2`, hence the smaller StdErr around its slope estimate.